# Python 3.8 how to install pip No module named pip

Tags: python-3.x

system: ubuntu
already: python2.7 python3.5 python3.6

install python3.8

```
pip install django
raise error No module named pip
```

i use

```
wget https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py
sudo python3.8 get-pip.py
```

fail

Answer (score 1):

The following worked for me:

```
sudo apt update
```

Python3: `sudo apt install python3-pip`
Python2: `sudo apt install python-pip`

Answer (score 0):

You must specify the version of python you are using if your system is referenced to the default (which I'm guessing is python 2)

```
$python3.8 -m pip install foo
```

Answer (score 0):

Python comes with `ensurepip` module which you can use to install python:

```
python3.8 -m ensurepip --upgrade
```